# jQuery stop other function's execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop another function's execution in my code, my JS code looks like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        <?php if ($saveMethod) : ?>
        $("#running").html('<b>Save</b>');
        <?php else : ?>
        $("#running").html('<b>Skip</b>');
        <?php endif; ?>

        $("#running").click(function() {
            // tried to stop customRedirect();
            return false;
        });

        <?php if ($redirectURL != '') : ?>
        customRedirect (10, "timer", "<?= $redirectURL ?>");
        <?php endif; ?>
    });
</script>
```

What I already tried:

```
$("#running").click(function() {
  // tried to stop customRedirect();
  return false;
});
```

I want to stop the execution of `customRedirect` if the user clicks on `#running`.

Comment: Where is PHP tag?

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens if the user click on $("#running") then I want to stop customRedirect() execution.

Comment: Mixing `html` `jquery` `php` like this is odd!

Comment: Put a live code for debug it, please.

Comment: You don't need this. There's only a single thread running JS in a browser, you can't run two separate functions at the same time, hence you don't need a way to stop another function.

Comment: @Teemu, I think he doesn't really know JS behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your `customRedirect` so maybe you can implement this into that function, but the trick is assigning the `setTimeout` to a variable so that we can clear it when we don't want it to happen anymore:

```
let delayedRedirect = setTimeout( function(){
        window.location = '<?= $redirectURL ?>';
        // or your customRedirect() if you have anything fancy
    }, 10 *1000);


$("#running").html('<b><?=$saveMethod? "Save" : "Skip" ?></b>');
$("#running").click(function() {
    clearTimeout(delayedRedirect);
});
```